# Initialization of the data source Failed (excel)

Tags: excel, oracle, database-administration

I have the database linked to excel it is working on my PC but when my manager access the excel file from his computer it comes up with an error message.

"Initialization of the data source Failed"

How can I grant authorization for other members to access the excel on their computers ?

I'll look forward to your reply

thanks in advance :)

Chao

Comment: What kind of database? How is it connected? There so many questions they would not fit in one single comment. We need MUCH more informations to help in a proper way... At least, you could try to set the workbook to "shared"... just [tag:excel], [tag:oracle] and [tag:database-administration] is not enough... sorry

Comment: i connect Oracle database with Power Query